# angular-route-segment calls previous controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started to use angular-route-segment for nested views. But I have a problem. When I route to another segment, it calls previous controller. Here is my problem

http://plnkr.co/edit/VUZM1ts5GvLnC2nf6QLe?p=preview

I would be gratefull if you have a solution for this

https://github.com/artch/angular-route-segment/issues/27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in angular-route-segment v1.2.1 ([commit](https://github.com/artch/angular-route-segment/commit/f3202a992c07f0cfd31287c8612178b97625df3a)).